# jQuery Mobile slider: how to use custom scale?

Tags: slider, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile slider. Let's say the range is 1 to 100. What I need is to make the scale exponential. In other words, moving the thumb by a given number of pixels on the left side would have a smaller effect than moving it the same number of pixels on the right side, towards 100. My goal here is to make it easy to pick values like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Differentiating between 96 and 100 is not necessary. So I want to devote more of the slider's range to the lower values.

Anyone have any ideas on how this might work? Or alternative approaches to solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm this sounds like a custom slider, Don't think anything out of the box would do this. To my understanding you want something like this: 1-----2-----3-----4-----5----6----7----8---9---10---11--12--13--14--15-16-17-18-19 so the spacing of the values is greater if the numbers are lower, correct?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i want. thanks for the diagram :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a solution by modifying the jQuery Mobile source to their slider widget to fit my needs.

Here's a link to a working version if anyone is interested:
http://media.pokerslug.com/js/jqm/eslide.js

It uses a simple x*x relationship to scale. To use it, call `$(element).eslider()`, but make sure the target doesn't have a "type=range" attribute.

A short demo can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/4XrhA/